# Warning: Invalid hook call and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack

I trying use ASP.NET Core with React. For bundling I use Webpack 5.

I have the next code (`index.jsx` file):

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            { value }
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Component rendering to block with id `root` in View.

But when I try open page, in console I saw [next error](https://imgur.com/a/DLgaz2l).

When I replace `useState(10)` to `React.useState(10)`, all works good.
But I want to use React functions without `React.`

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: could you please try adding this  `import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 in your code and make sure you have installed react-dom

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks for answer! I found solution of this problem =)

Answer (score 1):

Solution of this problem:

For React 18 [need to use `createRoot()`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot) function instead `ReactDOM.render()`